# All the casualties of the Gas attack on Superman Return universe hinted in crisis

Tags: character, arrowverse, crossovers, superman-returns, batwoman

In *Batwoman* S01E09 aka Crisis on Infinite Earths: Part Two, we see that *Superman Return* version of Clark had a big loss in a gas attack (supposedly by Joker):

[image]

and we do see some casualty names quickly, I got one such screenshot:

[image]

I can figure out:

- [Lois Lane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lois_Lane)
- [Perry White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_White)
- [Jimmy Olsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Olsen)
- [Ron Troupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Troupe)

Is there any other prominient DC comics character from the casualty list?

Answer (score 5):

Names visible:

[image]

- [**Brad Hunter**](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/brad-hunter/4005-38097/) (Comics - appears in 1 issue)
- [**Lacy Warfield**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Lacy_Warfield_(Donnerverse)) (Donnerverse - *Superman IV: The Quest for Peace*
- [**Mark Spencer**](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/mark-spencer/4005-106252/) (Comics - appears in 6 issues)
- [**Jeff Hage**](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/jeff-hage/4005-85286/) (Comics - 9 issues)
- ??
- Toni Allen
- [**Jennifer Owens**](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/jennifer-owens/4005-98733/) (Comics - 13 issues)
- Lois Lane
- Jimmy Olsen
- Jerome Curtis??
- ??
- ??
- [**Franklin Stern**](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/franklin-stern/4005-13049/) (Comics - 33 issues)
- Perry White
- Ron Troupe
- [**Dirk Armstrong**](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/dirk-armstrong/4005-13027/) (Comics - 32 issues) & Arrowverse Earth-38
- ??
- ??
- Jackie Winters
- [**Justin Moore**](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/justin-moore/4005-31550/) (Comics - 20 issues)
- [**Angela Chen**](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/angela-chen/4005-4682/) (Animated Series and then Comics - 29 issues)
- ??
- ??
- ??
- Kim Chiang (possibly a reference to a [**stunt double**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1548530/) on *Arrow*)
- Lisa Warren
- Ian Thomas (possibly a reference to a [**production designer**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0858938/?ref_=fn_al_nm_2) on *Batwoman*)
- Matt Brady?? (possibly a reference to the [Matt Brady](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/matt-brady/4040-79569/) who is a comic book writer who contributed to DC series such as *Young Justice* and the *Legion of Super-Heroes*.
- ??
- ??